# matplotlib loaded font appears fade on another machine

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python code using matplotlib which appears fine on a centos7 machine but on another centos7 machine, the font appears fade on the axes and legend:
[image]

My font is at `/usr/share/fonts/MyFont`
I checked that my font appears in
`/root/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache`
I've tried deleting and regenerating it.

```
def plot(data, format='png', width=400, height=400, font='MyFont'):
    font_size = max(3, int(width / 40))
    plt.cla()
    plt.clf()
    matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': font_size,\
                                'font.family': font})
    fig = plt.figure()
    _width = width / fig.get_dpi()
    _height = height / fig.get_dpi()
    fig.set_size_inches(_width, _height)
    plt.xlabel('this is x axis')
    plt.ylabel('this is y axis')
    plt.legend(bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure, loc=2)
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = x
    plt.plot(x, y, color='b', label='line1')
    plt.legend(bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure, loc=2)
    plt.title('this is title', fontweight='bold')
```

---

update:

I think the problem is that I have Lato-Hairline.ttf and Lato-Regular.ttf and on one operating system it is taking Regular as the default where on this new machine it is taking Hairline as the default which is so fade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf` and `Lato-Hairline.ttf` and then deleted
`/root/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache`.
It caused matplotlib to pick the other ttf file which is the proper regular form of the font.
I still would like to know how matplotlib determines which font is the regular form (default) such that it is behaviing randomly on different centos machines.